# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException with Google Play Services LocationClient

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, concurrentmodification

I am using Google Play Services LocationClient in Android. I do not have any problems getting location and location updates. However, when my app gets into the background, sometimes the app is stopped by android and this error y throwed:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:792)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:819)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.l$a$a.onServiceDisconnected(Unknown Source)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1102)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1116)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried to get rid off this error several times, this is how my code for locationClient is working right now:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    counter = 0;
    if (getLocationClient().isConnected()) {
        getLocationClient().requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(),
                providerListener);
        ;
        listen();
    } else if (!getLocationClient().isConnecting()){
        getLocationClient().connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    if(_locationClient!= null && !_locationClient.isConnected() && !_locationClient.isConnecting()) {
        try {
            connectLocationClient();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The methos getLocationClient and getLocationRequest are just to make sure this objects are not null:

```
private LocationClient getLocationClient() {
    if (_locationClient == null) {
        _locationClient = new LocationClient(context, this, this);
    }
    return _locationClient;
}

private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
    if (_locRequest == null) {
        _locRequest = new LocationRequest();
        _locRequest.setInterval(fixTime);
        _locRequest
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    }
    return _locRequest;
}
```

Any idea of what may be happening?

Thanks!

Edit:

Like shr pointed, calling connect() in onDisconnected was probably causing this, so I did remove that from there. Also calling requestLocationUpdates() in onConnected() can cause some troubles, so instead:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
   requestUpdates();
}
public void requestUpdates(){
   getLocationClient().requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(),this);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    //Use a handler instead to reconnect
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the same problem in a massively deployed app, at the google developer console crash report.

I suspect the problem was caused by my app trying to reconnect client in `onDisconnected()` method, though could not verify that while waiting for next release schedule for my app.

[Another stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373972/locationclient-auto-reconnect-at-ondisconnect) gave me excellent hints about the problem by suggesting (1) use `Handler` to avoid calling `connect()` method in the callback itself, (2) avoid re-using the `LocationClient` object and just destroy old one and create a new one.

I wish this be helpful.

Comment: You are absolutely right, calling connect() in onDisconnected was not a good idea. I also found that calling requestLocationUpdates() in the onConnected() method could also cause some problems, so instead I called another method and did the request call there.